# Loop Through Object Searching For Property And Modify Original Object on Success

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, javascript-objects

```
var myObj = 
    data: {
    {
    chairId: "CHAIRCHROME009",    
    relatedOrders: [
        {
            someProp: 45423234,
            data : {
                firstOrder: {},
                relatedOrders: [
                    {
                        someProp: 5757587,
                        data : {
                            firstOrder: {},
                            relatedOrders: [ ],
                            notifications: [
                                {
                                    notificationId: "CHAIR-0909FF",
                                    latestNotification: {                                
                                        latestNotificationAction: "New",
                                        priority: "High",                                
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            relations: [ ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                relations: [ ]
            }
        }
    ],
    relations: [ ]
}
}
```

How can i endlessly loop through an object containing arrays and objects, essentially searching for a `notifications` property.

In the example above, notifications is 2 levels deep in to `myObj`, however it could be 1 level or 100 levels. `notifications` will always be found under `relatedOrders` I then need to determine the value of `notifications.latestNotification.latestNotificationAction`

If no notifications are found, `null` or `false` should be returned.

I have tried:

```
function isThereRelatedOrders(myObj) {
    for(var k in myObj) {
        var v = myObj[k];

        if (k === "relatedOrders") {                
            isThereData(v[0]);
        }
    }
}

function isThereData(relatedOrder) {
    for(var y in relatedOrder) {
        var t = relatedOrder[y];

        if (y === "data") {                
            isThereNotification(t);
        }
    }
}

function isThereNotification(t) {
    for(var x in t) {            
        var j = t[x];

        if (x === "notifications") {
            console.lig('notifications found');
            if(j[0].latestNotification.latestNotificationAction  === "New") {                
                console.log('is new alert');
                // Add a property to my original myObj root level of alert: new
            }
            else {                
                console.log('is old alert');
                // Add a property to my original myObj root level of alert: old
            }
        }
        else if(x === "relatedOrders") {
            alert('SUB relatedOrders found');
            isThereRelatedOrders(j[0]);
        }
        else {
            alert('no notifications found');
        }
    }
}

isThereRelatedOrders(myObj);
```

With the above, once my code has got to calling isThereRelatedOrders() for the second time, it never hits the if statement.. I guess its becuase is now need to look for .data??

With the above executed, i would want something like this to be retunred:

```
var myObj = {
    chairId: "CHAIRCHROME009",
    alert: "New"
    ////////
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proposal uses an iterative and recursive approach to get the wanted property `notifications` and their content. If one found, the content is pushed into the `result` array. If nothing is found, then the array remains empty.

```js
function iter(o) {
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        o.forEach(iter);
        return;
    }
    if (typeof o === 'object') {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k === 'chairId') {
                chairId = o[k];
            }
            if (k === 'notifications') {
                o[k].forEach(function (a) {
                    if ('latestNotificationAction' in a.latestNotification) {
                        result.push({
                            chairId: chairId,
                            alert: a.latestNotification.latestNotificationAction
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            iter(o[k]);
        });
    }
}

var myObj = { data: { chairId: "CHAIRCHROME009", relatedOrders: [{ someProp: 45423234, data: { firstOrder: {}, relatedOrders: [{ someProp: 5757587, data: { firstOrder: {}, relatedOrders: [], notifications: [{ notificationId: "CHAIR-0909FF", latestNotification: { latestNotificationAction: "New", priority: "High", } }], relations: [] } }], relations: [] } }], relations: [] } },
    chairId,
    result = [];

iter(myObj);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Edit:

A solution which respects the toggle between `data` and `relatedOrders` properties.

```js
function iter(o, flip) {
    if (Array.isArray(o)) {
        o.forEach(function (a) {
            iter(a, flip);
        });
        return;
    }
    if (typeof o === 'object') {
        if ('chairId' in o) {
            chairId = o.chairId;
        }
        if (
            flip === 'relatedOrders' &&
            'notifications' in o &&
            0 in o.notifications &&
            'latestNotification' in o.notifications[0] &&
            'latestNotificationAction' in o.notifications[0].latestNotification
        ) {
            result.push({
                chairId: chairId,
                alert: o.notifications[0].latestNotification.latestNotificationAction
            });
            return;
        }
        flip in o && iter(o[flip], flipFlop[flip]);
    }
}

var myObj = { data: { chairId: "CHAIRCHROME009", relatedOrders: [{ someProp: 45423234, data: { firstOrder: {}, relatedOrders: [{ someProp: 5757587, data: { firstOrder: {}, relatedOrders: [], notifications: [{ notificationId: "CHAIR-0909FF", latestNotification: { latestNotificationAction: "New", priority: "High", } }], relations: [] } }], relations: [] } }], relations: [] } },
    chairId,
    result = [],
    flipFlop = { relatedOrders: 'data', data: 'relatedOrders' };

iter(myObj, 'data');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks, i like this solution, but where are you mimicking my isThereData function? This is pretty important check.

Comment: @OamPsy, i do not understand what it checks. is it just the property or some kind of content check?

Comment: you like to get a check for `relatedOrders` -> `data` -> `relatedOrders` and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt, using your data, but cleaned up to be valid...  Click on the "Run code snippet" button to run it.

```js
var myObj = {
  data: {
    chairId: "CHAIRCHROME009",
    relatedOrders: [{
      someProp: 45423234,
      data: {
        firstOrder: {},
        relatedOrders: [{
          someProp: 5757587,
          data: {
            firstOrder: {},
            relatedOrders: [],
            notifications: [{
              notificationId: "CHAIR-0909FF",
              latestNotification: {
                latestNotificationAction: "New",
                priority: "High",
              }
            }],
            relations: []
          }
        }],
        relations: []
      }
    }],
    relations: []
  }
};

function findAllNotifications(obj, chairId) {
  var result = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) {
    if (prop === 'chairId') {
      chairId = obj.chairId;
    }
    if (prop === 'notifications') {
      obj.notifications.forEach(function(notif) {
        result.push({
          chairId: chairId,
          alert: notif.latestNotification.latestNotificationAction
        });
      });
    }
    switch (typeof obj[prop]) {
      case 'object':
        result = result.concat(findAllNotifications(obj[prop], chairId));
        break;
      case 'array':
        obj[prop].forEach(function(sub) {
          result = result.concat(findAllNotifications(sub, chairId));
        });
        break;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

var result = findAllNotifications(myObj);
console.log("Result:", result);

// Doing this so you can see the result on the web page...
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(result)));

// To "reassign" to the original object:
// myObj= findAllNotifications(myObj);
```

Comment: thanks, i like this solution, but where are you mimicking my isThereData function? This is pretty important check.

Comment: I see the accepted answer addresses this.  Mine does not, I missed that :)

Answer (score 1):

[JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) is a perfect match for such tasks. It is very flexible and makes a lot of fun. 
You can download an actual fork here: https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath

#### 1. simple task, simple solution:

If there is only one chair in your data, you could easily get the chairId and let JSONPath do the rest:

```js
var result = {
    chairId: myObj.data.chairId,
    alert: JSONPath({json: myObj, wrap: false, path: '$..latestNotificationAction'}) || false
};
var resultString = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
document.write('<pre>' + resultString + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/s3u/JSONPath/master/lib/jsonpath.js"></script>
<script>
var myObj = {
    data: {
        chairId: "CHAIRCHROME009",
        relatedOrders: [{
            someProp: 45423234,
            data: {
                firstOrder: {},
                relatedOrders: [{
                    someProp: 5757587,
                    data: {
                        firstOrder: {},
                        relatedOrders: [],
                        notifications: [{
                            notificationId: "CHAIR-0909FF",
                            latestNotification: {
                                latestNotificationAction: "New",
                                priority: "High",
                            }
                        }],
                        relations: []
                    }
                }],
                relations: []
            }
        }],
        relations: []
    }
};
</script>
```

#### 2. complex task, simple solution:

If your data is more complex, you can use a callback function, which will be called every time a chair with a `latestNotification` is found:

```js
function find(obj, foundCallBack) {

  JSONPath({
      json: obj, resultType: 'parent', wrap: false, 
      path: '$..chairId', 
      callback: function(chair) {
          JSONPath({
              json: chair, resultType: 'parent', wrap: false, 
              path: '$..latestNotification', 
              callback: function(notification) {foundCallBack({
                  chairId: chair.chairId,
                  alert: notification.latestNotification.latestNotificationAction,
                  priority: notification.latestNotification.priority
              })}});
      }});
}
find(myObj, function(result){
   var resultString = JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
   alert(resultString);
   document.write('<pre>' + resultString + '</pre>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/s3u/JSONPath/master/lib/jsonpath.js"></script>
<script>
var myObj = {
    data: {
        employees: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        chairs: [
            {
                chairId: "CHAIRCHROME009",
                relatedOrders: [{
                    someProp: 45423234,
                    data: {
                        firstOrder: {},
                        relatedOrders: [{
                            someProp: 5757587,
                            data: {
                                firstOrder: {},
                                relatedOrders: [],
                                notifications: [{
                                    notificationId: "CHAIR-0909FF",
                                    latestNotification: {
                                        latestNotificationAction: "New1",
                                        priority: "High",
                                    }
                                },
                                    {
                                        notificationId: "CHAIR-0909FF",
                                        latestNotification: {
                                            latestNotificationAction: "New2",
                                            priority: "Medium",
                                        }
                                    }],
                                relations: []
                            }
                        }],
                        relations: []
                    }
                }],
                relations: []
            },
            {
                chairId: "CHAIRCHROME0077",
                relatedOrders: [{
                    someProp: 45423234,
                    data: {
                        firstOrder: {},
                        relatedOrders: [{
                            someProp: 5757587,
                            data: {
                                firstOrder: {},
                                relatedOrders: [],
                                notifications: [{
                                    notificationId: "CHAIR-090922FF",
                                    latestNotification: {
                                        latestNotificationAction: "New3",
                                        priority: "Low",
                                    }
                                }],
                                relations: []
                            }
                        }],
                        relations: []
                    }
                }],
                relations: []
            }
        ]
    }
};
</script>
```